# Flink filter before partition

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Apache Flink uses DAG style lazy processing model similar to Apache Spark (correct me if I'm wrong). That being said, if I use following code

```
DataStream<Element> data = ...;
DataStream<Element> res = data.filter(...).keyBy(...).timeWindow(...).apply(...);
```

`.keyBy()` converts `DataStream` to `KeyedStream` and distributes it among Flink worker nodes.

My question is, how will flink handle `filter` here? Will filter be applied to incoming `DataStream` before partitioning/distributing the stream and `DataStream` will only be created of `Element`'s that pass the filter criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will filter be applied to incoming DataStream before partitioning/distributing the stream and DataStream will only be created of Element's that pass the filter criteria?

Yes, that's right. The only thing I might say differently would be to clarify that the original stream `data` will typically already be distributed (parallel) from the source. The filtering will be applied in parallel, across multiple tasks, after which the keyBy will then reparition/redistribute the stream among the workers.

You can use Flink's web UI to examine a visualization of the execution graph produced from your job.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding `filter` is applied before the `keyBy`. As you said it is a DAG (D == Directed). Do you see any indicators which tells you that this is not the case?